# Canvas shifts down on first click [BabylonJS, Vue, Vuetify]

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js, babylonjs

**The problem**

When I first load the app locally, the first click shifts the canvas down by the height of the toolbar.

This is how it looks => https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqiF1UOT0C

This is how it should work => https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqiF1vOT0m

With this bug the first click doesnt even fire and the black square is not created on the canvas.

When I disable the toolbar this bug is not present.

How do I fix this? I need the toolbar to be visible.

**Tech**

Vue.js, Vuetify.js, Babylon.js

**App.vue**

`kw-Editor` is the canvas component below

```
<template>
  <v-app>
    <v-toolbar app>
      <v-toolbar-title class="headline text-uppercase">
        <span>KW2</span>
      </v-toolbar-title>
      <v-spacer></v-spacer>
      <v-btn
        flat
        href=""
        target="_blank"
      >
        <span class="mr-2">Test</span>
      </v-btn>
    </v-toolbar>

    <v-content>
      <kw-Editor/>
    </v-content>
  </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import kwEditor from './views/Editor'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
    kwEditor
  },
  data () {
    return {
      //
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
  html, body {
        overflow: hidden;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    #renderCanvas {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        touch-action: none;
    }
</style>
```

**kwCanvas.vue**

```
<template>
    <canvas id="renderCanvas" touch-action="none"></canvas>
</template>

<script>
    import { render } from './editor/render';

    export default {
        methods: {
            init() {
                render();
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.init();
        }
    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    /* div {
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    } */
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by removing this line from `App.vue`

> overflow: hidden;